# rails db:migrate fails due to duplicate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I got some problems about my database.

I've generated a model Comment once, but this Comment migration not what I wanted, so I drop it, and succeeded to drop. Now I try to re-generate it, and keep running `rails db:migrate`, but something went wrong.

It shows :

> "PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "comments" already exists",

I've checked my `schema.rb`, did not have this comment table.

My database using "psql", and Rails version is "Rails 6.0.2.2". I've been searched related problem, but seems like not what I faced.

Comment: I seems you ran the `rails g model Comment` twice and then destroyed it. But if this is in dev and data is not necessary Run `rails db:drop` -> remove dulplicate migration file in `db/migrations/` dir -> then run `rails db:create db:migrate`

Comment: thx Cdadityang, I did generate the database once, but I was missing some data when I generate the model, so I drop and I want to re-create it now, but still get "Did not find any relations. "

Comment: It's difficult to debug such things, if possible pls update your `db/schema.rb`, your files name in `db/migrate` folder, do you presently have `comment.rb` in model folder?

Comment: yes, I got the comment.rb folder which I create, but didn't has comment table, but it shows comment table has been exist, may I ask how to update db/schema.rb?

Answer (score 3):

according your description, I have also encountered this, this is what I tried and solved:

```
psql

rails db

\d:

drop table tablename;
```

hope to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not important you could just start fresh by dropping the current database and create a new one

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

If you are sure that those migrations already have been run before, then you can go and modify the schema migrations table directly where rails stores all migrations that have been run already.

First log into your postgres and choose the correct database

```
sudo -u postgres psql
\c db_name
```

then to view the current migrations in the schema table

```
select * from schema_migrations;
```

that will show you the current migrations that rails considers as done.

Then check you migrations folder, get the version of all the migration files you want to skip running, the file name starts with the version
for example
`20200401212538_add_country_name.rb`
the first numeric `20200401212538` part is the version

then insert them into the migrations table

```
insert  into schema_migrations VALUES ('version_of_migration');
```

Or you could also delete migrations so you could re-run them if you want to.

After that running `rake db:migrate` should work just fine without trying to recreate the tables.

Another solutions you might consider is that in your migrations you check first if table exists or not before trying to create it.